# jQuery selection within selection

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#addrow').click(function(){
     $('input').not(':visible').slice(0,1).addClass('required');
     $('.row').not(':visible').first().removeClass('hide'); 
 }
```

I want the `$('input').not(':visible')` selected *only if* within `$('row').not(':visible')`.

How do I chain these two together for the first line of the function, please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for very fast responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.row:hidden input:hidden').slice(0,1).addClass('required');
```

You can also see I've used the `:hidden` selector, which is the equivalent of `.not(":visible")`

Comment: This solution is the simplest, and it also works. I like how hidden was used instead of not visible to simplify things. James's answer above made me realize that I don't have to specify that the input is hidden even though the row is hidden. Thus, $('.row:hidden input).slice(0,1).addClass('required'); will also simplify things.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly, but one of the following should work:

```
//if the input has the row class
$("input.row:not(:visible)").slice(0,1).addClass("required");

//if the input is contained within an element using the row class
$(".row:not(:visible) input").slice(0,1).addClass("required");
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for submitting. I also realized that it assumes the input is hidden anyway, if the row that contains it is hidden. This was a big help, and will be combined below. I voted this one up.

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain selectors together like this:

```
$('.row').not(':visible').find('input').not(':visible').slice(0,1).addClass('required');
```

Comment: Not a bad answer by any means, but it could be greatly simplified.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes for jQuery selector newbie's I show them this and it greatly simplifies it in their heads.